# How to merge datasets with repeated measures

Tags: r, merge, left-join

I have Three datasets that I want to MERGE/JOIN.

This This examples only include the first participants I have a total of 25

df1

```
      ID     Grup   pretest
 1     1     A      2  
 2     1     A      1   
 3     1     A      3   
 4     2     B      NA  
 5     2     B      1   
 6     2     B      3  
 7     3     A      2   
 8     3     A      1  
 9     3     A      NA   
 10    4     B      2   
 11    4     B      1   
 12    4     B      3
```

df2 (this is missing one ID (5)

```
      ID     Grup   posttest  
 1     1     A      NA 
 2     1     A      5   
 3     1     A      4  
 4     2     B      2   
 5     2     B      4  
 6     2     B      3  
 7     3     A      5 
 8     3     A      6
 9     3     A      3   
 10    6     B      4 
 11    6     B      2  
 12    6     B      NA
```

Updated
df3( this have 5 Measurements for per ID)

```
     ID     Grup   traning

 1     1     A      2  
 2     1     A      6 
 3     1     A      3   
 4     1     A      NA  
 5     1     A      1   
 6     2     B      3  
 7     2     B      4 
 8     2     B      1  
 9     2     B     NA   
 10    2     B      2   
 11    3     A      1   
 12    3     A      3
```

I’ve been trying `merge()` and `full_join()` but both end up creating duplicates that I don’t want.

It won’t recognize the `ID` as an independent value, it’s creating 9 `ID`s for every `ID` value.

```
New <- merge(df1, df2, by= 'ID')  

New <- full_join(df1, df2, By = "ID")
```

Setting `all = TRUE` doesn’t help.

I need the dataset to look like this

```
     ID     Grup   pretest posttest traning
 1     1     A      2        NA.      3
 2     1     A      1         5.      4
 3     1     A      3         4.      4
 4     1     A      NA        Na.     4
 5     1.    A      NA        Na.     3
 6     2     B      3         3.      Na
 7     2     B.     2         5.      3
 8     2     B      Na        6.      2
 9     2     B      NA        Na.     5
 10    2     B      Na        Na.     4
 11    3     A.     1         2.      3
 12    3     A.     3         3.      4
```

Comment: Isn't it just joining by `ID` and `Grup`?

Comment: Nope, I That This is because I have a one less ID on df2

Comment: Adding data frames makes the question less clear. Generally only start by merging 2 data frames. Also, merging/joining works best with unique identifiers. If you have redundant values it produces all possible combinations like in your case. Also, where do the dots come from in the expected data frame?

Comment: sorry thats a typo

Answer (score 3):

Since you are relying on the order of the frames, you can simply use `cbind()`

```
cbind(df1,df2[,3,F])
```

Output:

```
   ID Grup pretest posttest
1   1    A       2       NA
2   1    A       1        5
3   1    A       3        4
4   2    B      NA        2
5   2    B       1        4
6   2    B       3        3
7   3    A       2        5
8   3    A       1        6
9   3    A      NA        3
10  4    B       2        4
11  4    B       1        2
12  4    B       3       NA
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! one problem that I did not Specify. Was t that one ID Did not show up to the post test. So this only worked if I removed that ID number and then joined it again later

Comment: the next step is to join the training numbers and they have high measurement how would I do that? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can add a helper column *iid* to separate the entries.

```
df1 <- cbind(iid = 1:nrow(df1), df1)
df2 <- cbind(iid = 1:nrow(df2), df2)
```

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, c("iid", "ID", "Grup"))[,-1]
   ID Grup pretest posttest
1   1    A       2       NA
2   1    A       1        5
3   1    A       3        4
4   2    B      NA        2
5   2    B       1        4
6   2    B       3        3
7   3    A       2        5
8   3    A       1        6
9   3    A      NA        3
10  4    B       2        4
11  4    B       1        2
12  4    B       3       NA
```

With **base R** `merge`

```
merge(df1, df2, c("iid", "ID", "Grup"))[,-1]
   ID Grup pretest posttest
1   1    A       2       NA
2   4    B       2        4
3   4    B       1        2
4   4    B       3       NA
5   1    A       1        5
6   1    A       3        4
7   2    B      NA        2
8   2    B       1        4
9   2    B       3        3
10  3    A       2        5
11  3    A       1        6
12  3    A      NA        3
```

##### Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L,
4L, 4L), Grup = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A",
"B", "B", "B"), pretest = c(2L, 1L, 3L, NA, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, NA,
2L, 1L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3",
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L,
4L, 4L), Grup = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A",
"B", "B", "B"), posttest = c(NA, 5L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L,
3L, 4L, 2L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2",
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! one problem that I did not Specify. Was t that one ID Did not show up to the post test. So this only worked if I removed that ID number and then joined it again later. What’s the next step is to join the training numbers and they have high measurement how would I do that? Thank you

Comment: @SimenLeitheTajet I have a vague idea what you mean, but to make sure i got it right can you please add an example to your question via edit at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is joining by rownames, eg. row numbers:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

left_join(rownames_to_column(df1), df2 %>% rownames_to_column() , by="rowname") %>% 
  select(ID = ID.x, Grup = Grup.x, pretest, posttest)
```

```
   ID Grup pretest posttest
1   1    A       2       NA
2   1    A       1        5
3   1    A       3        4
4   2    B      NA        2
5   2    B       1        4
6   2    B       3        3
7   3    A       2        5
8   3    A       1        6
9   3    A      NA        3
10  4    B       2        4
11  4    B       1        2
12  4    B       3       NA
```